# Why both radio buttons are selected with ng-value="true" and value="1"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am not sure why the button with `value="1"` and the button with `ng-value="true"` are both selected whenever you choose one of the two.

Any comments are appreciated.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="inputExample">
  <script>
   angular.module('inputExample', [])
     .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.chosen = "";
     }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="chosen" value="1"/>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="chosen" value="2"/>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="chosen" ng-value="true"/>
  <pre>{{chosen}}</pre>
</div>
</body>
```

Plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/qD6Kotx3nXrbtR4bv4Xr?p=preview

Comment: Any particular reason you used `value` for the first two but `ng-value` for the last one?

Comment: No, this was used accidentally. I resolved my issue by using `value` but I was wondering why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give the radio buttons `name` attributes, so all three of those radio inputs are ENTIRELY independent of each other for selection purposes, and all three can be selected.

Comment: They'd be independent *if* Angular weren't controlling them. I think the question is why value=1 and value=true both get selected **by Angular** when you click either of them.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! But even I give them name attributes, the radios don't behave correctly.

Comment: Yeah, giving them a common `name` just makes them behave even *more* oddly, not less.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason is that `1 == true` is true in JavaScript. E.g., Angular is doing a loose comparison with the radio button value when deciding whether to select it. So selecting the one with `true` or the one with `1` also causes the other to be selected. (The browser won't make them exclusive because you haven't given them `name`s [and if you do give the a common name, the behavior just gets even weirder].)

Comment: Thank you! If I do give them the same `name`, the radio button is not selected by one-click though. I need to click twice to make it actually selected.

Comment: @Rinny: That's what I meant by "the behavior just gets even weirder."